# Why doesnt the If statement in django work?

Tags: django

I was working from an example of an 'if' statement, but for some reason I cannot get it to work.
I tried every possible statement in the 'if', but it seems as though nothing makes it true for the if statement to run. Instead the Else statement runs.

Sample

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block content %}

<h2>Hardware Inventory</h2>

{% if hardware %}

<table id="datatable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Manufacturer</th>
            <th>Category</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    {% for item in hardware %}
        <tr>
            <td><a href="/inventory/hardware/{{ item.id }}">{{ item.name }}</a></td>
            <td>{{ item.manufacturer }}</td>
            <td>{{ item.kind }}</td>
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
</table>

{% else %}

<p>The inventory is empty.</p>

{% endif %}


{% endblock %}
```

Mine

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block content %}

<h2>News</h2>

{% if entry %}

{% for item in entry %}
<table id = "news">
    <tr>
        <td><a href="/news/Entry/{{ item.id }}">{{ item.title }}</a></td>
        <td>{{ item.body }}</td>
        <td>{{ item.pub_date }}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
{% endfor %}



{% else %}
<p>No News</p>
{% endif %}


{% endblock %}
```

My view.py for news, Im not sure how to write it correctly, but i tried different combinations, this one errors at the moment causes it to crash

```
def index(request):
    return render_to_response('news/index.html', {'Entry': Entry}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))

def Entry(request):
    Entry = Entry.objects.all().order_by('pub_date')
    return render_to_response('news/Entry.html', {'item':item}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Comment: Is your view setting the context for `entry`?

Comment: It might help if you show what you have in your view.

Comment: Note you don't actually need the `if`/`else` - the `for` tag takes an [`empty`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/templates/builtins/#for-empty) clause that does the same thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you're actually passing `entry` into the context. For example:

```
render_to_response('template.html', { 'entry': entry })
```

Unset variables behave as variables set to `None` in Django templates.

**UPDATE:**

Made some revisions to your view code; not even sure how you got to the template rendering with what you had.

Original:

```
def index(request):
    return render_to_response('news/index.html', {'Entry': Entry}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))

def Entry(request):
    Entry = Entry.objects.all().order_by('pub_date')
    return render_to_response('news/Entry.html', {'item':item}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Modified:

```
def index(request):
    entry = Entry.objects.all().order_by('pub_date')
    return render_to_response('news/index.html', {'entry': entry}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

I don't think you even needed the `Entry` method, so removed that. I kept your naming the same, but it's better form to call that variable `entries` since it's multiple items.

Comment: @Angela, it's case-sensitive - your `Entry` is upper-case, and the template is lower-case.

Comment: @Angela those cannot be your real views, as they both have errors that would prevent them from working (they both refer to undefined variables in the render_to_response calls).

Comment: Based on your view code, you are passing `item`, *not* `entry`, to the context, which isn't even defined in your view. And, of course, @John C is right, it's all case-sensitive.

Comment: Wow. I actually didn't even notice your various uses of `Entry` at first. `Entry` is your model, but you also store a queryset in it and even define a function using the same name. How has your code not caught on fire?

Comment: Thank you. I am new with programming in django. :)